# Spark bucketing hive metasore

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hive-metastore

I have two bucketed tables which are bucketed on the same column name . How does spark executors pick the files with same id distribution as into the same machine ?how can metastore  will be helpful ?

Answer (score 0):

From the master: https://towardsdatascience.com/best-practices-for-bucketing-in-spark-sql-ea9f23f7dd53

1. This here addresses the Hive Metastore but you could have another one.

> We need to save the data as a table (a simple save function is not
> sufficient) because the information about the bucketing needs to be
> saved somewhere. Calling saveAsTable will make sure the metadata is
> saved in the metastore (if the Hive metastore is correctly set up) and
> Spark can pick the information from there when the table is accessed.

2. Exector aspect.

> From the Metastore the Driver can gen an approach and DAG >for the Join, Aggr. with Optimizer and save on unnecessary Shuffles for repartitioning, as the data at rest is already partitioned  on disk. It applies to data at rest.

Also a good read: https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-sql/shuffle-join-spark-sql/read